# Example of using exiv2 to strip exiv tags from an image in Python

Tags: python, exiv2

I'd like to call exiv2 from Python to strip all EXIF tags from an image, then calculate the md5 hash of the image without the EXIF tags from python.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can shell out a subprocess ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)) and do this:

```
exiv2 -da a.jpg && md5 < a.jpg
```

or

```
jhead -purejpg a.jpg
```